# Dynamically loaded script is not using dynamically loaded css until I 'prettify' css in devtools source

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ember.js

I am experimenting with mounting an existing Ember app in a React app.  I have a React component that loads the vendor/app .css and then the vendor/app .js, with an await between each load.   The app shows up in the React component *but* it doesn't use any of the styles from the dynamically loaded css *until* I go into devtools/source, find the .css file, and click the 'prettify' widget ("{}").  Then it immediately repaints the screen with the css applied correctly.

I even tried doing a this.forceUpdate after the load.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or a way of triggering the browser to reapply the css from within my component's javascript?

Edit: More details about how things are arranged - see the code I'm using to load the 'emberapp' files below.

The React App, which I'm still learning, does a webpack build when starting (I realize that's probably not descriptive enough but will update when I learn more).  It runs a proxy server for the API wrapped around an express server that serves the local app.  Might be relevant - the React app components import their css at the component level.

During yarn start, react-app/dist gets destroyed so after the start finishes rebuilding and re-webpacking, I cd into react-app/dist and do a `ln /path/to/ember-app/dist/assets emberapp`

The ember-app/dist/assets contains

- emberapp.js
- emberapp.css
- vendor.js
- vendorapp.css

I also have all of my svg's inlined and loaded through the index.html - they obviously don't load right now and I'm OK with that.

This is really just a temporary setup for end-to-end API testing.  I was just really surprised that the css was ignored util I clicked something in devtools, and then was suddenly loaded.  I thought it might be a 'known' behavior.

My current goal is to repackage my ember app into an npm package that I can include in the build of the react app and 'import' its app/vendor js/css.

I know this isn't a great solution but we've got a lot of time built into the Ember App and don't have time to fully re-write it in React.  When we started the Ember App 'how will we merge this into another app when we are acquired' was not a consideration.

If anyone has any recommendations along embedding Ember, I'd be interested in that too.

```
const appendScript = scriptToAppend => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const _wrap = () => {
            console.log('_script onload wrap');
            resolve();
        };
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('src', scriptToAppend);
        script.setAttribute('async',true);
        script.onload = _wrap;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
};

const appendCss = cssToAdd => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const _wrap = () => {
            console.log('appendCss onLoad handler');
            resolve();
        };
        const elem = document.createElement('link');
        elem.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
        elem.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        elem.setAttribute('href', cssToAdd);
        elem.onload = _wrap;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(elem);
    });
};
export class MyWrapper extends React.Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        await appendCss(`${EMBED_SCRIPT_PATH}${VENDOR_SCRIPT_NAME}.css`);
        await appendCss(`${EMBED_SCRIPT_PATH}${SCRIPT_NAME}.css`);
        await appendScript(`${EMBED_SCRIPT_PATH}${VENDOR_SCRIPT_NAME}.js`);
        await appendScript(`${EMBED_SCRIPT_PATH}${SCRIPT_NAME}.js`);
        this.forceUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide more information about what files you're working with? like what is in your dist folder? and how do those get copied to the host app? is the host app react? how is that app serving normal static assets? are those being processed by webpack in the host app accidentally?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli Thanks for your response. I updated the original post and looks like I forgot a few things. The host app is react and in my environment, .css, .js, and .map files are served from its dist folder.  Others are proxied to a dev server.  I don't think webpack was processing the Ember source since I only link the ember-app after webpack build completes.  

Also this was only a temp arrangement to test accessing our API from Ember-embedded-in-React.  I'm now going to repackage as npm module and hopefully build into React app as imported files.  Not sure if css issue will persist.